# Sufficient conditions on $F$ to be able to switch the limit.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

If $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is given as strictly increasing in both arguments and continously differentiable, then for some $b\in\mathbb{R}$ under what conditions on $F$ can I write $$\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{F(a,b+\epsilon)-F(a,b)}{\epsilon}= \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \frac{F(a,b+\epsilon)-F(a,b)}{\epsilon}.$$ This is perhaps very easy and taught in Calculus but unfortunately I can't come up with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{F(a,b+\epsilon)-F(a,b)}{\epsilon}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(a,b).$$ Since $F$ is continuously differentiable it is

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{F(a,b+\epsilon)-F(a,b)}{\epsilon}= \lim_{a\rightarrow 0}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(a,b)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(0,b).$$

On the other hand, since $F$ is continuous,

$$ \lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \frac{F(a,b+\epsilon)-F(a,b)}{\epsilon}=\frac{F(0,b+\epsilon)-F(0,b)}{\epsilon}.$$ Thus, since $F$ is differentiable,

$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \frac{F(a,b+\epsilon)-F(a,b)}{\epsilon}=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{F(0,b+\epsilon)-F(0,b)}{\epsilon}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(0,b).$$

Thus, both sides of the equality exist and are equal.

**Note** It is not necessary to assume that $F$ is strictly increasing in any of the arguments.

Comment: You are right, thanks. One more question: if one knows $F(0,y)=0$ for all $y$, then is the above discussion sufficient to conclude $F_2(0,b)=0$?

Comment: @mathemagician Note that $F(0,y)=0$ means that $F$ is not strictly increasing in $y.$ But, if $F(0,y)=0$ then, as you have claimed, it is $F_y(0,b)=0.$

Comment: That's true. Actually my $F$ is non-decreasing so it should be good.